# Как динамически перестроить одну из форм на странице?

Tags: php, javascript

Есть проект на php. Все страницы статические, как правило по нескольку форм на странице, у каждой свой submit. Каждый submit приводит к перезагрузке страницы. Каждая форма строится своей отдельной функцией с помощью оператора `echo`.

Нужно переписать самые критические куски проекта убрав перезагрузку всей страницы по submit-у. С выполнением действия всё понятно, использование ajax помогает решить проблему. Но некоторые формы имеют довольно сложную логику отрисовки и хотелось бы задействовать существующие php-функции для этого. Возможно как-то на js удалить форму со страницы, а потом получив её новый html-код из php вновь отобразить?

Comment: Можете воспользоваться jq template. То есть у вас будет идти ajax запрос, который вернет данные и эти данные нужно будет просто подставить в jq template. А в самом template будет лежать структура новой формы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`removeChild` + `XMLHttpRequest` + `innerHTML` помогут сотворить вам эту жуткую затею.